# Error when retrieving data from SQL in nodejs

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, express

I connected the database to the project in node js and the connection works without a problem, but when I try to retrieve the data using the get operation, an error occurs that I could not solve

sql connection

```
const mysql = require("mysql");
const connection = mysql.createConnection({
host: "localhost",
user: "root",
password: "my password",
database: "test"
});
connection.connect(function (err) {
if (err) throw err
    console.log("connection");
})
module.exports = { connection }
```

Request from the page

```
const express = require("express");
const {connection} = require('../../dbConected')
const router = express.Router();

const {
getallstudents
} = require('../controllers/student')
router.get("/", getallstudents)

module.exports = router;
```

controllers

```
const {connection} = require('../../dbConected')
module.exports = {
    getallstudents:
    connection.query("SELECT * FROM test.student",function (err,result){
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log(result);
    })
}
```

the error

Route.get() requires a callback function but got a [object Object]

and

[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...

Thanks for the helpers

Answer (score 0):

Main issue here is the router.get requires a function but in example there is a object instead of it. So 'getallstudents' must be a function.

```
getallstudents:
connection.query("SELECT * FROM test.student",function (err,result){
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log(result);
```

Change this to

```
getallstudents: (function () => {
connection.query("SELECT * FROM test.student",function (err,result){
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log(result);
})(); //not sure about the last two parentheses
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass a callback which will be the controller for the `router.get`, RTM https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html

```
module.exports = {
    getallstudents: (req, res, next) => {
      // code here
    }
}
```

then inside this code:

```
connection.query("SELECT * FROM test.student",function (err,result){
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log(result);
})
```

rather than doing `if (err) throw err; console.log(result);`, send the response back.

```
connection.query("SELECT * FROM test.student",function (err,result) {
  if (err) {
    return next(err);
  }

  res.json(result);
})
```

or like:

```
module.exports = {
  getallstudents: async (req, res, next) => {
    try {
      res.json(await connection.query("SELECT * FROM test.student"))
    } catch (err) {
      next(err)
    }
  }
}
```

<sub><sup>..but what is `next(err)`, rtm: https://expressjs.com/en/guide/error-handling.html#writing-error-handlers</sup></sub>

Comment: I was able to fix the error and everything works the error was port of sql
Now I tried the this code

Comment: I'm glad you got it fixed, happy dayz

Comment: If you can help me with another problem I encountered  Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

```
const {connection} = require('../../dbConected')
module.exports = {
    getallstudents:(req, res) => {
       const select = connection.query("SELECT * FROM student")
       let json_select = JSON.stringify(select)
            res.status(200).json({
                json_select
            }).catch(error => {
            res.status(500).json({
                error
            })
        })
    }
}
```

And I get an error in the json file
the err

"message": "Converting circular structure to JSON\n    --> starting at object with constructor 'Query'\n    |     property '_timer' -> object with constructor 'Timer'\n    --- property '_object' closes the circle"

and GET /getallstudents 500 2.939 ms - 224